# Save query results inside Excel file

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I'm a little desperate because I can't use T-SQL Function

> OPENROWSET

because I don't have privileges to test my services, anyway.

are there any way to save my query results from SQL SERVER (without using OPENROWSET) to EXCEL?

Comment: TITLES DO NOT NEED TO SHOUT.

Comment: Is this just going to be an infrequent thing? If so I'd just copy & paste. If it's something you want to set up on a scheduled basis I'd recommend creating an SSIS package.

Comment: Due I did not find any solution, I created a DTS 2000 and export my rows to a csv file, that's not the best alternative but It's done.